# Fill Stripe Elements Card with Playwright

Tags: stripe-payments, playwright

I want to fill in a [Stripe Card Element](https://stripe.com/en-cy/payments/elements) using Playwright.

The regular locators don't seem to work. The following for example does nothing:

```
await page.fill('iframe input[name="cardnumber"]', '4242424242424242')
```

How can I fill the card inputs (number, CVC, expiry date, postal code) with Playwright?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Stripe Card Elements](https://stripe.com/en-cy/payments/elements) render those fields inside an `iframe` so we need to grab the `contentFrame` and proceed from there:

```
// probably need to use a more specific selector here
const stripeIframe = await page.waitForSelector('iframe')
const stripeFrame = await stripeIframe.contentFrame()

const cardNumInput = await stripeFrame.waitForSelector('input[name="cardnumber"]')

// @NOTE card no must be filled for rest of input fields to appear with
// appropriate [name] attributes.
await cardNumInput.fill('4242424242424242')

const cardExpInput = await stripeFrame.waitForSelector('input[name="exp-date"]')
const cardCVCInput = await stripeFrame.waitForSelector('input[name="cvc"]')
const cardZipInput = await stripeFrame.waitForSelector('input[name="postal"]')

await cardExpInput.fill('12/50')
await cardCVCInput.fill('123')
await cardZipInput.fill('99999')
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's the newest way to achieve this using Playwright's [FrameLocator API](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator) which was added to v.1.17.

```js
const stripeFrame = page.frameLocator('iframe').first();
await stripeFrame.locator('[placeholder="Card number"]').fill('4242424242424242');
await stripeFrame.locator('[placeholder="MM / YY"]').fill('04/30');
await stripeFrame.locator('[placeholder="CVC"]').fill('242');
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for 2024

```
await page.frameLocator('[title="Secure card number input frame"]').locator('input[name="cardnumber"]').fill('4242424242424242');
await page.frameLocator('[title="Secure expiration date input frame"]').locator('input[name="exp-date"]').fill('01/50');
await page.frameLocator('[title="Secure CVC input frame"]').locator('input[name="cvc"]').fill('123');
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It's best to be specific with IDs and class names:

```js
const iframeLocator = this.page.frameLocator('div.__PrivateStripeElement iframe')
const cardNumber = await iframeLocator.locator('#Field-numberInput')
await cardNumber.click()
await cardNumber.fill('4242424242424242')
const expDate = await iframeLocator.locator('#Field-expiryInput')
await expDate.click()
await expDate.fill('12/34')
const cvc = await iframeLocator.locator('#Field-cvcInput')
await cvc.click()
await cvc.fill('567')
const country = await iframeLocator.locator('#Field-countryInput')
await country.selectOption('United States')
const zipCode = await iframeLocator.locator('#Field-postalCodeInput')
await zipCode.click()
await zipCode.fill('12345')
```

Used [Playwright's API documentation for FrameLocator](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator) and [Stripe's Test Payment Card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)